# find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}n^2x}{e^9n}$

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}n^2x}{e^9n}$$

Can I put the switch the limit symbol into this?$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2x}{e^9n}$$

Comment: Looks like it diverges.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}n^2x=\infty$ for $n\geq 1$, so each term of the sequence is '$\infty$'. If that makes sense, then you have a constant sequence whose members are '$\infty$'.

Answer (score 0):

By considering the priority between the two limits, note that the inner limit diverges to $\infty$ for sufficiently large $n$ and the outer limit is simply $\lim_{n\to\infty}\infty$ which is $\infty$.

Comment: but if I switch the limit symbol, that is dealing with the n limit first, I can apply L'H rule. Can i do that?